# WPF bind to a list

Tags: wpf, data-binding, grid, datacontext

I have a user control whose users I want to have them set a `DataContext` on to bind to a list of objects.  In my control, however, I want to display that list in a `Grid`, but in a non-trivial order.  The column/row of display of each element will be determined by some code I will write.

So I cannot do a straight databinding in my control, I need to write code that will read the `DataContext` and then do the processing to correctly position each element.

How would a relative WPF newbie go about doing that?  I guess the part I don't understand is what the code in my usercontrol will look like to read the `DataContext` items so that I can process them.

**EDIT:** Clarification:  I want to stress I want to bind to the XAML `Grid` element, not some other kind of grid or `DataGrid`. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible way to achieve that is to use a Converter. You could create a Converter which converts the input list into another list where the order has been changed. Then you could use a "normal" databinding which will use the Converter.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good, but how do I bind the Converter's output to a grid, with locations for each element somehow specified?

Comment: You can change the ItemsPanelProperty of your ListBox to Grid. Then you can create a style that databound the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties and set it to the ItemsContainerStyle.